# Tiles dont turn right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I am making a website, http://phaidonasgialis.xyz. I want to make the tiles to turn and every other tile back. Until now it works except one small bug, the tile that you pressed does not turn back until you click second time.Any help would be thankful.

Here is the code:

$(document).ready(function() {

var previous = [];
  $('.flip-card').each(function(i, obj) {

```
$(this).click(function() {
  if ($(this).find('.flip-card-inner').hasClass('flip-card-transform')) {
    $(this).find('.flip-card-inner').removeClass('flip-card-transform');

  } else {
    $(this).find('.flip-card-inner').addClass('flip-card-transform');
    previous.push(this);


    if (previous.length >= 2 && previous[previous.length - 2] != previous[previous.length - 1]) {

      for (var i = 0; i < previous.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).find('.flip-card-inner').hasClass('flip-card-transform')) {
          $(previous[i - 1]).find('.flip-card-inner').removeClass('flip-card-transform');
          console.log("2")

        } else {
          $(this).find('.flip-card-inner').addClass('flip-card-transform');

          console.log("3")
        }

      }

    }

  }
});
```

});

Comment: Please put all relevant code in the question so that people don't have to go off-site in order to replicate the problem and understand what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you use `previous` as an array? Just make it a variable that holds a single object. First flip back the already flipped card (previous) first. Then flip the clicked card and assign it to the `previous` unless the previous and the current is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like a card to flip back automatically after a certain period of time? If so then you just should set a **`Timeout`** and remove the class `flip-card-transform` from `.flip-card-inner`.

***Aside note***: you should definitely optimize your code by using a variable instead of doing `$(this).find('.flip-card-inner')`– converting `this` to jQuery object and searching trough its children every time when you need your `flip-card-inner`. Also instead of `$('.flip-card').each(...)` you could directly use `$('.flip-card').click(...)`. And also as **Harun Yilmaz** suggested in his comment you don't need previous as an array...

So something like this should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var previous
  var timeout
  $('.flip-card').click(function () {
    var cardInner = $(this).find('.flip-card-inner')
    if (cardInner.hasClass('flip-card-transform')) {
      cardInner.removeClass('flip-card-transform')
      clearTimeout(timeout)
    } else {
      cardInner.addClass('flip-card-transform')

      // Set a Timeout
      timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        cardInner.removeClass('flip-card-transform')
      }, 2000) // set whatever time sutable for you

      // Also as Harun Yilmaz suggested in his comment you don't need previous as an array
      if (previous && previous.hasClass('flip-card-transform')) {
        previous.removeClass('flip-card-transform')
      }
      previous = cardInner
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: the idea is when i open a tile every other turns back, i update my code but still when i click on a tile and then to an other, and go back to previous tile, both remain open.